# How to show the Popup over the Modal screen in Semantic-react-ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI library to show some content over the Modal.
There is a button over the Modal upon which after clicking we see a popup giving some info.
The challenge is that the popup appear behind the Modal screen.
How can I bring the popup up in front of the Modal. I tried Googling but no solution is effective at the moment.

I did try z-index as well.
Yes Sir.I used inline style to give zindex of value 1 to the modal and zIndex of value 999 to the Popup. Like here below-

```
//Modal.js
render(){
<Modal style={{zIndex:1}}>
          <MyComponent />
</Modal>
}

//MyComponent.js
render(){
<Popup
       trigger={<Button> Click Me! </Button>
       style={{zIndex:999}}>
<Popup.Content>
     Hi There. I am Popup content
</Popup.Content>
```

Unfortunately it did not work. :(

NOTE- Both the Modal and the Popup are the components available from Semantic UI library itself.

[Popup](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/popup)

[Modal](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal/)

Comment: Have you tried to change the z-index of the modal (or popup) ?

Comment: apply the zIndex to Popup style set higher value like 999

Comment: Yes Sir.I used inline style to give zindex of value 1 to the modal and zIndex of value 999 to the Popup. Like here below-

//Modal.js
render(){
<Modal style={{zIndex:1}}>
          <MyComponent />
</Modal>
}
//MyComponent.js
render(){
<Popup
       trigger={<Button> Click Me! </Button>
       style={{zIndex:999}}>
<Popup.Content>
     Hi There. I am Popup content
</Popup.Content>

Unfortunately it did not work. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <Popup
     style={{ zIndex: 9999999 }}
 />
```

Apply zIndex to Popup. to keep that higher than modal's zIndex keep it greater than ui-dimmers zIndex which is 99990.

Comment: Ah I see. I had to put z-index value much higher than I originally did. Thank you sir :)